# Regex match rule for scrollTop gets overridden

Tags: javascript, regex, scrolltop

On my site I implement smoothscroll for all anchors by using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

But I have also a scrolltop at the end of the site that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></a>
```

My problem is that the following code gets totally ignored (scrolltop doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

         $(window).scroll(function(){
             if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                 $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
             } else {
                 $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
             }
         }); 

         $('.scrollup').click(function(){
             $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
             return false;
         });

     });
```

Basically I think the 'a[href^="#"]' regex match gets priority over the single '.scrollup' selector. Is there a way to say "any anchor except the sharp alone" or a better method to fix this behaviour? I want to keep smooth scroll for all anchors, but also having a empty "#" anchor for scrolltop and still make it work.

Comment: in jQuery if you use `$().click(...)` or `$().on('click', ...)` those functions get stacked. so both functions get executed. use `$().unbind('click')` to first remove the already added function from your `scrollup`

Comment: Tryed adding $().unbind('click') just before  $('.scrollup').click(function(), still it doesn't work.

Comment: Could be that your two `$(document).ready ()` function (they also get stacked) execute in the wrong order. try putting all your code in just one `ready()` function.

Comment: No need actually, but this is really curious... If I put $('.scrollup').unbind('click'); inside the $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) function, scrollTop will work but without smoothscroll, while if I put it outside it, everything works smoothscroll included. Is there any specific reason for this?